# DrawString EllipsisCharacter has different behavior in test program than production library?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdi+, drawstring

I was drawing on a bitmap in a test program using the following code. The ellipsis worked as expected. I moved the code to a .dll called on our webserver, and the ellipsis behavior changed to have no '...' and to trim at the word boundary:

The text is "This is a long title". In the test program, I get "this is a lo...", but in production I get "this is a".

```
StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
format.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;
format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

g.DrawString(Title, TitleFont, TitleColorBrush, TitleRectF, format);
```

Both sets of code are using .NET 4, both have the same bitmap initialization code copied from this test program, and the bitmaps are identical otherwise.

Any idea what I can do to get the ellipsis behavior to work? Are there any flags in the .NET environment I should be setting that I get for "free" in an app but not a dll?

Comment: Is not advised that you use the Graphics class or anything on the Drawing namespace in a web server, probably that may be the cause of your problem, so i suggest you to try an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for looking out for us, but it's worked great for years and it isn't really an option to get rid of it. Someday we might move our image rendering to a windows service on another server, but I'm stuck with it until then. However, taking your advice to exclude the webserver, I modified the test program to use the new assembly - same problem. Code inside EXE renders properly, same copy & paste code in assembly used from EXE has this ellipsis bug behavior.

Comment: Aha! Ellipsis has nothing to do with it, just a copy paste bug on the DrawString rectangle that caused DrawString to wordwrap beyond the clipping boundary. My bad! Thanks for helping me exclude distractions.

Comment: Care to share? :)